# How to mark CRM 2011 Early Bound Data Context as Internal?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I am using CRMSVCUTIL.exe to generate an early bound data context against my CRM 2011 On Premise instance. I noticed in the generated code that the context is marked public. I would prefer this to be internal in order to hide the context from the consuming tier. It is easy enough to open the generated file and change the access modifier manually, but I would prefer this to be automatic if there is a setting to do that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a command line parameter or setting for this specifically; however, you could automate it by using the command line and then modifying it appropriately.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff681563.aspx